# How would you compare a spoken word to an audio file?

Tags: iphone, voice-recognition

How would you go about comparing a spoken word to an audio file and determining if they match?  For example, if I say "apple" to my iPhone application, I would like for it to record the audio and compare it with a prerecorded audio file of someone saying "apple".  It should be able to determine that the two spoken words match.

What kind of algorithm or library could I use to perform this kind of voice-based audio file matching?

Comment: Yes it is work. Work that you'll have to do yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx does voice recognition and pocketSphinx has been ported to the iPhone by Brian King

check https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit

He has provided excellent details and made it easy to implement for yourself. I've run his example and modified my own rendition of it.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a basic use for this library? I've tried to init a VKController object with no success. (there's apparently a need for some  *.conf file..)

Answer (score 1):

You should look up Acoustic Fingerprinting see wikipedia link below.  Shazam is basically doing it for music.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I discovered this library today:

http://www.ispikit.com/

Comment: On their page is cleary pointed out to `Contact us at info@ispikit.com` if you like to have the android version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a neural networks library and teach it to recognize different speech patterns. This will require some know how behind the general theory of neural networks and how they can be used to create systems that will behave a particular way. If you know nothing about the subject, you can get started on just the basics and then use a library rather than implementing something yourself. Hope that helps.